# Ignore New Page Before if following page only has 2 records

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is my formula from `Section3 Details > Details > Paging > New Page Before` - The rowcount is the Item Description:

```
IF {@RowCount} > 23 AND {@RowCount} < 45 THEN
    IF Remainder (RecordNumber, {@RowCount} - 2) = 0 THEN
        TRUE
    ELSE FALSE

ELSE IF {@RowCount} > 68 AND {@RowCount} < 87 THEN

    IF Remainder (RecordNumber, {@RowCount} - 2) = 0 THEN
        TRUE
    ELSE FALSE

ELSE IF {@RowCount} > 110 AND {@RowCount} < 131 THEN

    IF Remainder (RecordNumber, {@RowCount} - 2) = 0 THEN
        TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
```

[image]

[image]

The first picture has a white space below it. And I need the whole second page to look like the second image. (For example, I have 50 records. I want the last page to be like that, it has 2 remaining data)`. If the data has 2 records only, it should display all in the first page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you elaborate this `And for the second page is I need the whole page to be like that (for example I got 50 data then I want the last page to be like that, it has 2 remaining data). If the data has 2 records only it will display all in the first page.` or post a picture how do you want the report to look like.

Comment: Any time you write a Crystal formula in the style of `IF (Clause) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE` a developer somewhere cries. You'll get the same result with just `(Clause)` - So in your case, `(Remainder (RecordNumber, {@RowCount} - 2) = 0)` will return either True or False.

Comment: @Siva it look likes the picture two. for example I have many data like 5 pages the 5th page must be like the picture 2 it has two data.